# MongoDB all replica set members are "OTHER"?

Tags: mongodb

I am setting up a MongoDB replica set using EC2's image: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00CO7AVMY/ref=dtl_recsim_B007IBMJPI_B00CO7AVMY_3

MongoDB version 2.6.5

I have managed to set up replicaset by not enabling "auth=true" in my config file.

I went ahead to add "auth=true" back into my config file and restarted mongodb on all 3 of my instances.

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

After restarting, I got into mongo shell and it is displaying

```
myReplicaSetName:OTHER>
```

I am unable to run rs.status() because I don't have a PRIMARY.

```
 "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetGetStatus: 1.0 }"
```

Comment: Can you share the config file?

Answer (score 1):

When you enable authentication you must also specify (at the very least) [a keyfile](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.keyFile) also (see step 1 in the [procedure for enabling auth](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#procedure)), setting `auth=true` without a keyfile will mean that the mongod processes will not be able to authenticate with each other (this is what the keyfile is used for).  Hence they cannot communicate, elect a primary, respond to heartbeats etc.

Follow the guide/docs linked above to create and configure a keyfile and your replica set should come up and elect a primary without an issue.